# Unable to remove elastic search service during Azure DevOps Server upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

Trying to upgrade TFS 2018 to DevOps Server 2019. Stuck at readiness checks screen. It wants me to remove elasticsearch service.

[image: installer stuck at readiness check]

The service is stopped.

And the path mentioned in the service properties, specifically the **Search folder**, does not exist `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018\Search\ES\elasticsearchv5\bin\elasticsearch-service-x64.exe //RS//elasticsearch-service-x64` **does not exist**.

No way to run `service -remove` from the bin folder.

[image: elasticsearch service properties]

[image: command prompt shows search folder does not exist]

**Relevant log:**

```
[Info   @07:49:10.510] +-+-+-+-+-| Running Service Not Installed: Verifying the following Windows service is not installed: elasticsearch-service-x64 |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.511] 
[Info   @07:49:10.511] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying the following Windows service is not installed: elasticsearch-service-x64 |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.511] Starting Node: VSEARCHSERVICENOTINSTALLED
[Info   @07:49:10.511] NodePath : VINPUTS/Conditional/Progress/Conditional/VSEARCHSERVICENOTINSTALLED
[Info   @07:49:10.511] Verifying that the following service is NOT installed: elasticsearch-service-x64. Machine: ..
[Info   @07:49:10.512] Node returned: Error
[Error  @07:49:10.512] The following Windows service is installed on your computer: elasticsearch-service-x64. Remove elasticsearch-service-x64 to continue. Read the troubleshooting guide (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=828578) for more details.
[Info   @07:49:10.512] Completed Service Not Installed: Error
[Info   @07:49:10.512] -----------------------------------------------------
[Info   @07:49:10.512] 
[Info   @07:49:10.512] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifySearchIndexLocation: Verifying that the search index location path is valid. |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.512] 
[Info   @07:49:10.512] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that the search index location path is valid. |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.512] Starting Node: VSEARCHINDEXLOCATIONVERIFIER
[Info   @07:49:10.512] NodePath : VINPUTS/Conditional/Progress/Conditional/VSEARCHINDEXLOCATIONVERIFIER
[Info   @07:49:10.513] Node returned: Success
[Info   @07:49:10.513] Completed VerifySearchIndexLocation: Success
[Info   @07:49:10.513] -----------------------------------------------------
[Info   @07:49:10.513] 
[Info   @07:49:10.513] +-+-+-+-+-| Running Verify ElasticSearch port is available: Verifying that a port is available in range 9200-9299 |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.513] 
[Info   @07:49:10.513] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that a port is available in range 9200-9299 |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.513] Starting Node: VSEARCHESPORTAVAILABLE
[Info   @07:49:10.513] NodePath : VINPUTS/Conditional/Progress/Conditional/VSEARCHESPORTAVAILABLE
[Info   @07:49:10.514] Port: 9200 is available for configuring elasticsearch
[Info   @07:49:10.514] Node returned: Success
[Info   @07:49:10.514] Completed Verify ElasticSearch port is available: Success
[Info   @07:49:10.514] -----------------------------------------------------
[Info   @07:49:10.514] 
[Info   @07:49:10.514] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifySearchServiceAccount: Verifying that the search service account name and password is valid. |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.514] 
[Info   @07:49:10.515] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that the search service account name and password is valid. |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @07:49:10.515] Starting Node: VSEARCHACCOUNTVALID
[Info   @07:49:10.515] NodePath : VINPUTS/Conditional/Progress/Conditional/VSEARCHACCOUNTVALID
[Info   @07:49:10.515] Node returned: Success
[Info   @07:49:10.515] Completed VerifySearchServiceAccount: Success
[Info   @07:49:10.515] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I noticed you selected search in the upgrade wizard, can you go back and deselect the installation of search.  This will let you proceed with the upgrade, then you can reenable search after the fact by itself.  It might be easier that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, just run the command in cmd as an administrator
`sc delete elasticsearch-service-x64`

According to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-delete), the `sc delete` command removes the service from the registry without the need for an executable in the specified path.

After this command close all windows referring to the windows service and request a new check in Azure DevOps Server 2019

Comment: Since it allows you to configure search post installation as well I basically unchecked the search feature to move the wizard along. And it completed without issues.